# Can an variable be a combination of two dichotomous variables?

Tags: categorical-data, t-test, mean

I was wondering if a variable can be a combination of two dichotomous variables?

For example, supposed I am looking at a group of patients with a specific mean blood chemical level, let's say cotinine,  that also answered yes to having condition A=emphysema and condition B=lung cancer.

Can we look at mean levels of cotinine in patients who answered yes to both and compare them to those who answered no to both?

My first inclination is yes this is possible, but I have it in my mind that I should run a correlation test first on the two dichotomous variables.

Comment: that is possible. This variable would have 4 levels to it - a certain cotinine level with answers yes/no to A and B